# Hector_SLAM, changing from Fuerte to Groovy?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a version of Hector_SLAM configured for ROS Groovy? If yes, how do I move my Hector_SLAM settings, et. al. developed for Fuerte to the Groovy configuration?

Asked another way: How do I move over to Groovy without breaking my Hectpr_SLAM?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62087/hector_slam,-changing-from-fuerte-to-groovy?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are .deb packages for groovy available that can be installed using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-hector-slam
```

Checking svn out and building from source should also work. There are no major changes between fuerte and groovy versions of the system and it should work just the same using both distros (case in point: We've been using it very successfully using groovy at the [RoboCup German Open 2013 a few days ago](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKI378kadp8)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-05**:
I'll give it a try. If I get stuck I may haunt your pit area when we are in Eindhoven looking for help.